# How to display "Showing 1 to 10 of X entries" on top of the table

Tags: jquery, datatables

How to display "Showing 1 to 10 of X entries" on top of the table?

My code is below:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var oTable = $('#GridView1').prepend($('<thead></thead>').append($('#GridView1').find("tr:first"))).DataTable({
        "columnDefs": [
                 { "targets": [0, 1, 3,4], "searchable": false }
        ],
        "oLanguage": {
            "sSearch": "Search by Category: "
        }

    });

});
```

Comment: By default, search box already appears on top, see [this example](http://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/zero_configuration.html). Can you clarify what you mean or provide a screenshot of what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: "Showing 1 to 10 of 60 entries" i want this text on top of table? how can i cahange its positions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> **SOLUTION**

Use [`dom`](http://datatables.net/reference/option/dom) option to define the table control elements to appear on the page and in what order.

```js
var oTable = $('#GridView1')
   .prepend(
      $('<thead></thead>')
         .append(
            $('#GridView1').find("tr:first")
         )
      )
    .DataTable({
       "columnDefs": [
          { "targets": [0, 1, 3,4], "searchable": false }
       ],
       "oLanguage": {
           "sSearch": "Search by Category: "
       },
       "dom": "lifrtp"
    });
```

Also add the following CSS rule to adjust appearance of the informational control.

```
.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_info {
    clear:none;
    margin-left:10px;
    padding-top:0;
}
```

> **DEMO**

See [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4v6vndbm/) for code and demonstration.

Comment: Awesome ... in future i love to be a javaScript Developer...<3

Comment: @SherinGreen, use something like `dom: 'lifrtpi'`. See [`dom`](http://datatables.net/reference/option/dom) option for more details.

Comment: This is good, but on the apparently legacy version I'm using, the solution doesn't work, and the info div is below the table HTML, which is all drawn by DataTables... it'd be nice to have an option in the config to place it at the top (more intuitive and useful if you ask me), but maybe the source team had some reason not to.